# Have Date heading and break line at change in date

Tags: php, html

I have three fields. An id, an Article-link address and a date.  The links are currently populating the page horizontally by date. For example I have 6 links for 2/26/2017 and 6 links for 2/25/2017. I would like to know if it's possible to add that when the date changes, the date would come in at the bottom of each column and then have a horizontal break line. Then, it would go to the next day in the database. This is the format I'd like.

```
Link1............................Link2...............................Link3
Link4............................Link5...............................Link6
2/25/2017......................2/25/2017...........................2/25/2017
____________________________________________________________________________
Link7............................Link8...............................Link9
Link10...........................Link11..............................Link12
2/26/2017......................2/26/2017...........................2/26/2017
____________________________________________________________________________
```

---

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("*****");
$result = mysql_query("select Article from crypto");
// set up loop counter 
$col_count = 0; 

// start table and first tr 
echo '<table border="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;"><tr>'; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
   // if you have output 3 cols then end tr and start a new one 
   if ($col_count == 3) { 
      echo '</tr><tr>'; 
      //  and reset the col count 
      $col_count = 0; 
   } 
   // always output the td 
   echo '<td>' . $row['Article'] . '</td>'; 
  // and count the column 
  $col_count++; 
} 

// then close off the last row and the table 
echo '</tr></table>';  

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This question has multiple problems.  The question is unclear.  You are using mysql_. You are only querying for `Article` but asking about ids, links, and dates.  Please do a question edit.  Also, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I clarified the article is the link address and I do want the date to be included in the answer.  Not sure what you mean by multiple problems?

Comment: Your query only collects one column per row in the resultset but you want to process three columns.  It is possible that I am misunderstanding your question, but that is because it is so poorly written.  Your code basically needs a full rewrite and the question may be flagged as too broad/unclear/unsalvagable.

Comment: I have 1 field of Article-links and I spread out the results over 3 columns and that is already working perfectly.  I was just asking if there is a way to separate results by date with a break line and also list that date above the break line.   This one is very difficult to explain.

Comment: If you don't understand what I'm talking about you can see the results I'm seeking at http://althedge.xyz  where it's hard coded manually  or you can look at what I'm trying to do with the mysql database at http://althedge.xyz/index4.html    Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are having quite a lot of difficulty explaining your problem.  Where is the $date portion of your query and code?  You can't bake a cake without accessing the ingredients.  The SO Community wants to help you, but you aren't giving us the necessary information.

Comment: I looked at your source code, where does `<sub>02/26/2017</sub>` come from?  Is the date value built into the Article?  If so, you will have to extract the date value from the Article string before you can make comparisons/sort/group.

Comment: The date field is called date and it's one of the 3 fields in the mysql database.  I didn't do anything with it yet because I didn't know how to go about writing the code to group the article-links by date.   In the original code not done with mysql, I just typed in <sub>02/26/2017</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what your looking for i did substitute your `mysql_connect` for a simple array if you want to see that code here it is:
`//$ar = array("Link1","Link2","Link3","Link4","Link5","Link6","02/25/17");`
`//$arz = array("Link1","Link2","Link3","Link4","Link5","Link6","02/26/17");`

This Should Show A Way To Get Your Desired Results By matching the `/` in your date part of your sql array:

```
<?PHP
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("*****");
$result = mysql_query("select Article from crypto");
$col_count = 0; 

// start table and first tr 
echo '<table border="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;"><tr>'; 
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($row as $rows) { 
   // if you have output 3 cols then end tr and start a new one 
   if ($col_count == 3) { 
      echo '</tr><tr>'; 
      //  and reset the col count 
      $col_count = 0; 
   } 
   // always output the td 
   if(preg_match("/\//", $rows, $b)) echo '<td>' . $rows . '</td><td>' . $rows . '</td><td>' . $rows . '</td></tr><tr><td colspan=\'3\'><hr>&nbsp;</td></tr>'; 
   else echo '<td>' . $rows . '</td>';
  // and count the column
  //echo '</tr>';
  $col_count++; 
}

// then close off the last row and the table 
echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks.  I could be totally misunderstanding your code but I definitely need it to work from the mysql database and I don't want to have hard code the dates or any of the links.  I want that to all be done just by entering the info into the database.

Comment: thats what this shows is from the database... you can change the `foreach($row as $rows) { ` to `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ` but then the `if(preg_match("/\//", $rows, $b))` changes to `if(preg_match("/\//", $row['Article'], $b))` and every `$rows` to `$row['Article']`

Comment: Could you explain what will these changes do?  Sorry for my lack of knowledge.